non-interactively resolve git conflict on generated file
In my case we're using python poetry, so the lockfile in question is poetry.lock, but I imagine this use case is meaningful for many other kinds of lockfiles in git.
We frequently find ourselves with a merge conflict on poetry.lock. That file is generated and managed by the poetry command, and should never be directly human edited. When poetry.lock is in conflict, if pyproject.toml is also in conflict, a human has to fix it. But when poetry.lock is the only file in conflict, I have a git alias I run.
$ git help popo
'popo' is aliased to '!git reset -- ./poetry.lock && git co ./poetry.lock && poetry lock --no-update && git add ./poetry.lock'

When doing a long interactive rebase, I often find myself running this command after every line in the rebase todo. (I've also tried using exec git popo after every line in the rebase todo, but that is too late to prevent the conflict and it just ends up slowing the rebase down with commands that ultimately do nothing.)
Is there a way I can tell git, essentially, "if there's a conflict and the only file in conflict is {X}, run this command and then rebase --continue without interacting"?

Check git custom merge drivers.

Thanks, @eftshift0, here's a link for myself and any lurkers to look at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver
